# rowSum <- apply(documents , 1, sum) and Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)

Tags: r, lda, topic-modeling

When I try to run a topic model, I try to remove the
"

```
  Each row of the input matrix needs to contain at least one non-zero entry
```

"
error by adding this line of code:
rowSum <- apply(documents , 1, sum) ,

but then I get
"Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)"

and I'm not sure why.

```
rowTotals <- apply(dtm , 1, sum) #Find the sum of words in each Document
dtm.new   <- dtm[rowTotals> 0, ]  
g = LDA(dtm.new,10,method = 'VEM',control=NULL,model=NULL)
```

Comment: Surely it is a very big dataset. Try your luck with `rowSums` instead of `apply(dtm,1,sum)` . also `rm(dtm)` after you create `dtm.new`, then `gc()`

Comment: It's not clear from your question, is `dtm` a "simple" `data.frame`? By that, I mean are all columns atomic vectors such as `integer` and `numeric`, or are there list-columns (e.g., tidy models)? Also, do you have anything other than `integer`/`numeric` in your frame? If so, your `apply` is going to "corrupt" your data (though I might expect a different error).

Comment: ... following r2evans comments, if `dtm` is a sparse matrix then you could *probably* use a `rowSums` / `row_sums` version applicable to the `dtm` class. What does `class(dtm)` give please?